# Value error while trying to group by the pandas data frame and get the row having maximum value for one of the columns

Tags: dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to use data frame and trying to group by the below data-frame by the field Name and want to get the rows having maximum value for the column 'high'.

```
    Name    date        high    low
0   20MICRONS   06-03-2020  31.55   27.45
1   AGRITECH    06-03-2020  33.2    30.2
2   20MICRONS   09-03-2020  30      26.85
3   AGRITECH    09-03-2020  30.45   26.4
4   AGRITECH    11-03-2020  28.75   26.55
5   INFY        11-03-2020  695.95  669.05
6   20MICRONS   13-03-2020  24.7    19.45
7   AGRITECH    13-03-2020  26.45   22.55
8   INFY        06-03-2020  744     729.1
9   INFY        09-03-2020  725.85  697
10  20MICRONS   11-03-2020  28.25   24.65
11  20MICRONS   12-03-2020  28.7    21.5
12  AGRITECH    12-03-2020  28.5    24.85
13  INFY        12-03-2020  670     627.5
14  INFY        13-03-2020  667     570
```

required output with the maximum of 'high' column for all the stocks group-wise:

```
    Name    date        high    low
8   INFY        06-03-2020  744 729.1
1   AGRITECH    06-03-2020  33.2    30.2
0   20MICRONS   06-03-2020  31.55   27.45
```

likewise it would be helpful if I get the minimum as well. i have tried max() and idxmax() functions as below but i recive value error. could you please help me.

```
df[['IndexName','date','high']].loc[df[['IndexName','date','high']].reset_index().groupby(['IndexName'])['high'].idxmax()]
```

did not help but.

Comment: I understand, you'd like to get `INFY` using `max`. But I don't understand, which criteria you want to get for `AGRITECH` and `20MICRONS` ? Those don't have any *minimum* nor *maximum* values. Please be more specific about how you want to get them.

Comment: thanks for taking time to look into this. even AGRITECH and 20MICRONS do have the high and low values if you see the first list. I want the code to get me the out put rows as shown in the second list(3 rows) which are having the maximum value for the column 'high'.

Comment: i am able to solve my problem as above using an additional for loop and comparison. However would like to know if there are any other better way of doing this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i am able to solve my problem as below using an additional for loop and comparison.

```
grouped=df.reset_index().groupby('Name')

dfinal= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','date','high','low'])

if(sys_Arg_highlow==1):

    for group in grouped:
       dfinal = dfinal.append(group[group['high']==group['high'].max()])

else:
    for group in grouped:
      dfinal = dfinal.append(group[group['low']==group['low'].min()])
```

However , i would like to know if there are any better ways of doing this. thank you.